# Uniqueness of systems of nonlinear equations and the inverse function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am reading about the inverse function theorem and this is an example provided by the text:
[image]

Are we able to obtain any global information on the existence and uniqueness from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$? How do  we know that there is not another point not $(1,1)$ and far away from U such that also maps to $(2,4)$? Also, it is still possible to have points outside the U neighbor of $(1,1)$ that maps to points in the neighbor of $(2,4)$ correct?

Comment: please type the mathematics with mathjax; as it stands I can’t access imgur (using work internet) and therefore your question

Comment: And the inverse function theorem by itself will not give you  global information. It could be possible with other ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot gain any global information. The example correctly says that $(1,1)$ is the only solution on some neighborhood $B_{\epsilon}(1,1)$. This is because
$$\det{DF(1,1)} = \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}\right)(1,1) = 15 \neq 0.$$
The inverse function theorem guarantees that a continuous, differentiable function is injective and maps open sets to open sets on some open open neighborhood if the determinant of the derivative matrix is nonzero.

Consider $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=x^{2}$. The "determinant" of the derivative matrix is just 2x. This satisfies $\det(Df(a)) \neq 0$ for $a \neq 0$. Obviously, the function $x^{2}$ is injective on $(0,2a)$ (or $(-2a,0)$) for any nonzero $a$. But at $a=0$, the function is not injective on any interval since $(-r)^{2}=r^{2}$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$.